# Django admin Inline Forms not working on production

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a django admin inline form that works locally but doesn't work on production. Locally:

[image: Locally]

And on Heroku:
[image: On Heroku]

I don't have a clue why this could be. Any ideas? Any advice will help.

This is the code:

```
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [OrderItemInline, TiptiItemInline, MessageInline]
    search_fields = ['client', 'shopper', 'state']
    list_display = ['date', 'client', 'state', 'address', 'payment_method']
    readonly_fields = ['client', 'address', 'billing_info', 'payment_methods', 'history', 'rate']
```

Comment: Make sure your production user has the appropriate permissions to add those objects.

Answer (score 0):

I had to restart the uWSGI server instead of reloading it, to fix this problem.